# Why Is My String Not Converting To An Integer?

Tags: c#

I have a list of items, each with numbers, followed by a space, and then a word. Think scrabble.

```
36 adore
36 adore
27 amigo
31 amino
28 amiss
```

I am trying to use the 2 digit number as an organizational item to which I can rank the words by order of value.

My list, ComJoined is shown above.

My Code is:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < ComJoined.Count; i++)
{
    if (i + 1 <= ComJoined.Count)
    {
        int one = (Convert.ToInt32(ComJoined[i].Substring(0, 2)));
        int two = Convert.ToInt32(ComJoined[i + 1].Substring(0, 2));
        if  (one <= two)
        {
            string Stuff = ComJoined[i];
            ComJoined.Insert(i + 1, Stuff);
            ComJoined.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason it says that "Input string was not in a correct format." I read that this meant the string didn't have a int value, but the part being converted, the first two digits, obviously do. Why is this occurring?

Comment: Does your input contain the dash and a space in front of the number or not?

Comment: Make your life easier by separating the `Substring` and the `Convert.ToInt32` into two code lines. Like `var numString = ComJoined[i].Substring(0, 2); int one = Convert.ToInt32(numString);` This way, you can easily check in the debugger which part of the ComJoined strings you are really extracting and trying to convert...

Comment: No, there is nothing in front of the items within the list. So its literally "32 apple"

Comment: Will do tudor..

Comment: `int.TryParse()` is a better option to convert.

Comment: When you check in the debugger, pay attention for any superfluous white-spaces that might sit at the beginning of the strings. This can easily be overlooked when not looking closely... ;-)

Comment: Also note that if `i + 1` is exactly equal to `ComJoined.Count`  you will get an exception when trying to access `ComJoined[i + 1]` since the last element is at index `ComJoined[ComJoined.Count - 1]`.

Comment: The result is that its the same error, but isolated to this code: int one = Convert.ToInt32(numString);

Comment: You will get an `IndexOutOfRange` exception for sure.

Comment: Pls, check the content of numString when the error occurs. What do you see precisely? (pay attention to any possible white-spaces)

Comment: If your input string starts the way you say (i.e. `33 abc` etc) and without a dash in front it shouldn't give you the error you say it does. Unless you have whitespaces in front or something like that.

Comment: Sorry, I found the error. I had an input of an old string set as an argument

Comment: Also, your way of 'ordering' the list is, well, not very pretty. Here's an alternative solution. https://dotnetfiddle.net/KTDDUP

Comment: Thanks! I've been trying to accurately sort this list for a long time!

Comment: if you have a list like this: `List<string> ItemsList = new List<string> { "36 adore", "36 adore", "27 amigo", "31 amino", "28 amiss"};` try ordering ot this way: `List<string> OrderedList = ItemsList.OrderBy(s => s, StringComparer.Ordinal).ToList();` and see what comes out of it. If there are errors in the string composition, it will be clear.

Comment: When you run into a problem like this, break it into two lines (`var temp = ComJoined[i].Substring(0,2)` and `int one = Convert.ToInt32(temp)`) then run it in debug mode and inspect `temp`. You might be surprised by what you see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to sort the list descending, according to the 2 digit code, and all items start with the two digit code?

This would just be a linq one-liner: `var sortedList =  ComJoined.OrderByDescending().ToList()`

Answer (score 0):

This might be less complex of a solution to your problem:

```
var words = new SortedDictionary<int, string>();

foreach (var com in ComJoined)
{
    string[] splitCom = com.Split(' ');

    // Assuming your data is in the correct format. You could use TryParse to avoid an exception.
    words.Add(int.Parse(splitCom[0]), splitCom[1]);
}

// Do something with the sorted dictionary...
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> word in words)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", word.Key, word.Value);
```